# Style an input textbox like jQuery Redmond theme

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, textbox

I am using jQuery in my web page with Redmond theme from jQuery-ui team. **The problem is that the input textboxes remain unstyled by Redmond theme.** This creates a not-too-impressive look-and-feel. Is there any way to create an appropriate style for input textbox elements so they blend with Redmond theme in jQuery?

Comment: Just fyi there is no built in way to accomplish this and input text boxes are notoriously difficult to style in a cross browser friendly way.  I'm not even sure exactly what you're looking for.  If you post a rough screen shot or go into detail of exactly what you're looking for then ith a CSS tag then someone here would be able to help you make that.

Comment: TJ - I would say something with a bluish shadowed border, OR light bluish gradient background in text box.

Comment: Alright, I took a shot at it and posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment there is no built in way to accomplish this.  What you can do is take some of the colors used in the theme and apply then to the textbox to get something that looks similar.

Here's a couple options that I made that are based off the look and feel of the datepicker.

```
/* Option 1 */
​input[type=text] {
    background: #5C9CCC url(http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/themes/redmond/images/ui-bg_gloss-wave_55_5c9ccc_500x100.png) 50% 50% repeat-x;
    border: 1px solid #4297D7;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

/* Option 2 */
input[type=text] {
    background: #DFEFFC url(http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/themes/redmond/images/ui-bg_glass_85_dfeffc_1x400.png) 50% 50% repeat-x;
    color: #2E6E9E;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 1px solid #C5DBEC;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

**Example** - http://jsfiddle.net/XjCjR/1

Comment: For some reason, the styles you gave are not being applied. My code is exactly as in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11387140/restore-text-of-jquery-combobox-to-selected-options-text-in-case-the-text-has-b

Comment: It's because my selector is assuming a `type=text` is being applied and in your example code it wasn't.  Here's an example of it working - http://jsfiddle.net/eVqvM/1/.